# Writing a script to update recurring tasks

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to prepare sheet that will automatically move the completed tasks from tab to another and update the task's date to one from now.

What I want to achieve:

1. The row 2 from Monthly sheet should flow to completed task whenever the **column E** is updated to `'Done'`.
2. The completed tasks tab will be sort of like an archive to help me see how well I have done my project's task in the past.

Can you please review my script and help me figure out what issue there is?

Here is the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12CFtKbmgyrKBsRJaPsQT2O_H39gkD_ODVEOHt3XlfOU/edit?usp=sharing

Here is script:

```js
    function onEdit(e) {

    var row = e.range.getRow();
    var col = e.range.getColumn();
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks");
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var activeRow = spreadsheet.getRowHeight(row);
    var active_range = sheet.getActiveRange();

    if(col = 10 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Monthly Sheet" && 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,10).getValue() === "Done" && 
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,10).getValue() !== ""  ) {
 

 
  spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex() + ":" + active_range.getRowIndex()).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Completed Tasks'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange(active_range.getRowIndex() + ":" + active_range.getRowIndex()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, make `col == 10` instead of `col = 10`.

Comment: Fixed that but nothing changed. The data doesn't get copied and pasted into the other tab.

Comment: Make the file public so we can view it . Right now it requires permission.

Comment: Also if you go to **View => Executions** you will see if you get any error messages. That would really help you and us identify the issue/s.

Comment: Please check now. I've made it public.

Comment: you want to **copy** the task from one row to another or **move** it? Namely, delete it from the monthly sheet

Comment: I want to copy the task that has its status updated as 'Done' and move to 'Completed Tasks' sheet. The task in 'Monthly Sheet' will get updated and the monthly due date will increase by 30 days to the next month.

Comment: I posted my answer. Also make sure the format between the two sheets is same, otherwise you will think that wrong values were transferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The main issue with your code is that it is not checking for **column
  E** which is `col == 5`.
- I also removed some unnecessary code and made some modifications to produce the
  desired result.

**Solution:**

```
function onEdit(e) {

const row = e.range.getRow();
const col = e.range.getColumn();
const sheet = e.source.getSheetByName("Completed Tasks");
const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
const active_sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

if(col == 5 && row > 1 && active_sheet.getName() === "Monthly Sheet" && e.range.getValue()=='Done') {
  
 var ref_date =  active_sheet.getRange(row,4).getValue();
 ref_date.setDate(ref_date.getDate() + 30);
 active_sheet.getRange(row,4).setValue(ref_date); 
 active_sheet.getRange(row,col+1).setValue(new Date());
 const values = active_sheet.getRange(row,1,1,active_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 sheet.getRange(lastRow+1,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
 active_sheet.getRange(row,1,1,active_sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent(); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That is very helpful. Any chance you can help me update the 'Monthly Sheet' due date by 30 days? So, whenever the script runs, the due date should automatically increase by 30 days. Any way to do that?

Comment: @GoogleGuy check the updated answer. Keep in mind the format in your file is: M/D/YYYY

Comment: You're literally the best person I've virtually met in 2020! Thank you so much!!